# How to reset options to default in SAS 9.3?

Tags: sas

I have set a number of global options during a session in SAS 9.3. Some of the options were, for example, `pagesize`, `firstobs`, `obs`, `date`, `pageno`, `linesize` and so on. Later I decided to reset all options to default, not one by one, but all at a time. But do not find how!
Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: @Hong Ooi  It is a data analysis questions. May be you have misunderstood because of it's simplicity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is answered in [SAS Blog](http://blogs.sas.com/content/sastraining/2012/08/14/jedi-sas-tricks-reset-sas-system-options/).  The tl;dr is that there is no default way to do this in SAS, instead you need to capture the current options with `getoptions` at the beginning of your program and then set the options back to this captured set later on with `call execute`.